# How to increment column group by an ID Value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a 3 columns: ID (Varchar type), Age(INT type) and amount ($). The real table is 100K Rows: the table list every amount the customers receive for each age.

| ID | Age | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A01 | 1 | 10 |
| A01 | 2 | 11 |
| A01 | 3 | 12 |
| A02 | 90 | 50 |
| A02 | 100 | 51 |
| A02 | 110 | 52 |

I need to increment each Age of each customers to 120 and get something like this

| ID | Age | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A01 | 1 | 10 |
| A01 | 2 | 11 |
| A01 | 3 | 12 |
| A01 | 4 | 13 |
| A01 | n+1 | ... |
| A01 | 120 | 1500 |
| A02 | 90 | 50 |
| A02 | 100 | 51 |
| A02 | 110 | 52 |
| A02 | 111 | 53 |
| A02 | n+1 | ... |
| A02 | 120 | 600 |

It's my first time doing loop and after several tries this is the best I could wrote but it doesn't work.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT [id], [Age], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [id] ORDER BY 
     [Age])AS Rnk INTO tableRanked FROM  MyTable
        
           DECLARE @Agefirst AS INT 
           DECLARE @Agelast AS INT 
           DECLARE @AgeCurent AS INT 
           DECLARE @id as nvarchar(max)
               
           SET @Agelast = 120
           SET @id = 0
           SET @AgeCurent = 0
                
           WHILE(@AgeCurent <= @Agelast)
           BEGIN
           SET @AgeCurent = @AgeCurent+1                
           INSERT INTO tableRanked ([Id],[Age])
           SELECT [Rnk], [Id], [Age] FROM  tableRanked 
            SET @id = @id+1

            END
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: *Doesn't work* is not useful description of the error. Please, describe what is wrong or what the error you have.

Comment: The while is loading at the infinite and nothing is incremented.

Comment: Well that's what you wrote in the query: go in a loop and insert the data into itself again and again. It has no filter. Not clear what you want exactly, but looks like either a running sum, or some kind of adding extra rows from the current max up to 120

Comment: @charlieface Hi, as i said in my message I have absolutely no clue about how doing what I want to have in result. I want for each ID the age to be incremented by 1 until the age is 120. Then it goes to the next ID and do the same for 100K Customers I have. I understand how to increment an Age but how can I do that for each ID? How can I have 1 ID and each age incremented then it goes to the next ID? I don't know how to do that this is why I'm here

Comment: Can you define what you need better? Do you need rows to start from 1 and go to 120 for every ID, or start from the first available `Age` or from the last available `Age`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a loop (or a recursive CTE, which is also a loop) you could you use a [numbers function, or tally table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1).  Numbers functions use few resources and are very quick.  From your code it appears each ID should span the age range 1 to 120.
Something like this

```
;with unq_id(id) as (
    select distinct id
    from MyTable)
insert into tableRanked
select ui.id as ID, fn.n as Age, isnull(m.Amount, 0) Amount
from unq_id ui
     cross join dbo.fnTally(1, 120) fn
     left join MyTable m on ui.id=m.Id
                            and fn.n=m.Age
order by ui.id, fn.n;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand how the end amount can be 1500 or 600 if increased by 1 each. But if I assume that that's an error in the question and put that aside, I suggest you can use an `INSERT ... SELECT ...` with a recursive CTE here. Then there's no need to fiddle around with procedural code here.

```
WITH cte
AS
(
SELECT 1 is_anchor,
       x.id,
       x.age,
       x.amount FROM
       (SELECT r.id,
               r.age,
               r.amount,
               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY r.id
                                  ORDER BY r.age DESC) r
               FROM tableranked r) x
       WHERE x.r = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 is_anchor,
       c.id,
       c.age + 1,
       c.amount + 1
       FROM cte c
       WHERE c.age + 1 <= 120
)
INSERT INTO tableranked
            (id,
             age,
             amount)
SELECT c.id,
       c.age,
       c.amount
       FROM cte c
       WHERE c.is_anchor = 0
       OPTION(MAXRECURSION 120);
```

You can get the anchor rows, these are the ones with the maximum age per ID, using `row_number()`. Mark them as anchor row to filter them out in the `SELECT` part of the `INSERT ... SELECT ...` and don't insert them again.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=67deadb6478737682bd483f79c3f618b)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer.The amount i showed there is just an example to show what kind of data I have, The amount is not supposed to be incremented. I'm not familiar with cte so I'll check what you did and try to understand your logic and why and what I failed in my query